# Reverse engineering and fitting Poisson distribution function?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, probability, poisson

I'm looking to take a set of percentages/probabilities and reverse engineer them via a Poisson distribution to figure out the inputs.

This stems from already doing the inverse of this. I'm looking to predict football (soccer) outcomes. So let's say I have a home team with an expected output 1.35 goals scored in a match and an away team with an output of 1.15 goals. If I wanted to calculate the probability of a 2-0 home win, I would just do:

POISSON.DIST(2, 1.35, FALSE) * POISSON.DIST(0, 1.15, FALSE) = probability of 2-0 home win

(I recognize the application of Poisson here is not perfect math or scenario analysis for predicting the outcome, let's ignore that).

I can of course also say that neither side will score more than 10 goals, and then if I sum up all the individual scores in which the home team wins (i.e. 1-0, 2-0, all the way to 10-9) I can get the probability of a home win, and follow similar logic for a draw, or an away win, which are the 3 possible outcomes in this sport.

This is all straightforward and I'm not having any problems with that. What I am looking to do now is go backwards. **If I have the probabilities or percentages of the three outcomes (home win, draw, away win), how would I reverse engineer this (I'm thinking either a formula or using Solver) to get the two inputs around how many goals the home team is expected to score, and how many goals the away team is expected to score?**

My ideal outcomes would be:

Col A = home team win prob (ie 40%), Col B = draw prob (ie 30%), and Col C = away team win prob (ie 30%) - these would all be numbers I generate myself as inputs from real world data

What I need help with is **Col D = home team expected goal output, Col E = away team expected goal output... how do I calculate D/E based on A-C?**

Thanks a ton in advance for any insight!

Comment: This question may be a better fit for the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange. The hard part seems to be how to figure out the math equation, but it doesn't seem like it would be something too complex to translate to Sheets afterwards.